# How to save response file in DBCA oracle 12c

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

I have read the oracle documentation for 12c on saving response files from dbca and have found this:

> Starting with Oracle Database 11g Release 2 (11.2), you can save all
>   the installation steps into a response file during installation. You
>   can click the Save Response File button on the Summary page to do
>   this. Later, this file can be used for a silent installation.

However, I am at the summary page in DBCA and do not see an option to record a response file. I poked around other pages in DBCA and could not find it either. Does anyone have any information on how to record a reponse file for 12c DBCA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above documentations refers to OUI (Oracle Universal Installer), not DBCA.
Saving response files in DBCA is available starting with version 12.2.

See the below example (Save Response File in bottom right corner):

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I'm on 12.1 which would explain that. Upon further digging it seems that if I want to create a repeatable silent process for creating databases, I should use a database template. Is that correct?

Comment: @Sol Yes, you can use templates or save the scripts in DBCA and run those scripts later.